# Add up all Subarrays together

Tags: python, loops, numpy

I am stuck.

I'm new to python and need a little help.

I want to create a function, preferring array form, to add all my subarrays together. Not using numpy.sum.

```
amp , amp2 = 1., 1.
epochs = 2
sfreq, duration = 10., 5
times = np.arange(0, duration, 1 / sfreq)
nfft = 512

x =  amp * np.sin( 2 * np.pi * 200 * times            ) + nse1
y = amp2 * np.sin( 2 * np.pi * 200 * times + np.pi/2  ) + nse2

x2 = np.array_split(x,epochs)
y2 = np.array_split(y,epochs)

Rxy = np.zeros((epochs,nfft/2+1), dtype=np.complex)
freqs_xy = np.zeros((epochs,nfft/2+1), dtype=np.complex)
for i in range(epochs):
    Rxy[i], freqs_xy = mlab.csd(x2[i], y2[i], NFFT=nfft, Fs=sfreq)

    Rxy.shape
    (epochs ,257)
```

I want to have a function that will add Rxy[0] + Rxy[1] + ... + Rxy[epochs-1]

By using numpy.sum(Rxy) it only gets me ONE value.
But using Rxy[0] + Rxy[1] I add all values together. and gain the size

```
Rxy.size
(257,)
```

Anyone got an idea how to get the second version ?!

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Why don't you use the built-in sum?

Comment: How this Rxy object is created?

Comment: I am not sure I am getting your question.. Are you asking hot to sum arrays? Could you specify the inputs and the output you would like to get?

Comment: I hope now it's clear what I am looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify `axis` in `np.sum`. In your case `axis` is `0` as you want to add all sub-arrays which actually are rows here. So, try this:

```
np.sum(Rxy, axis=0)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Sometimes I miss the wood for the trees or situation depending dumbness.

Comment: Please downgrade my question, it is to pathetic.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you're trying to turn an 2D array into a 1D array. If so, you can use [`ndarray.flatten`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flatten.html).

If you meant a list of lists, you can use list comprehension for that:

```
x = [item for sub_list in whole_list for item in sub_list]
```